# Mysql2::Error: Table 'query_app_development.queries' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `queries`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Controller

```
class QueriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        @query = Query.new      
    end

    def create
        @query = Query.new
        @query.query_string = params[:query][:query_string]

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js{} 
        end
    end    
end
```

Model

```
class Query < ActiveRecord::Base


    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_reader :query_result, :query_string

    def query_string=(query_str)
        @query_string = query_str
        establish_connection :readonly_db
         @query_result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query_str)
    end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151029054443) do

  create_table "readonly_dbs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",               limit: 255
    t.string   "email",              limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password", limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                  null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Database.yml

```
readonly_db:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: #somedatabase
  pool: 5
  username: readonly_user
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: query_app_development


test:
  <<: *default
  database: query_app_test


production:
  <<: *default
  database: query_app_production
  username: query_app
  password: <%= ENV['QUERY_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

This is  the app i am creating kinda like query browser.
But it is throwing an error saying "Mysql2::Error: Table 'query_app_development.queries' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `queries`"

"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in QueriesController#new"

Comment: Do you have `queries` table in the **DB**?

Comment: nope.query is the model name.

Comment: You should be having queries table in the DB.

Comment: With the columns that you need.

Comment: can i get your email id i can explain in detail what i am trying to do?

Comment: You can explain in your question instead.

Comment: I am trying to first authenticate user using devise gem which uses the rails database.once the user is been authenticated he get access to query browser with different database.query browser has one text box and submit button.